# How to view errors for WebApp in Azure portal and what configuration it is required

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring

I am working on the ASP.Net MVC 4.8 application. It does have Logs file log4net and it was deployed in on-premises. Now it has been migrated to Azure. Now I am trying to find out some errors and other logs information however I am not able to find where to go and look for the logfile. I have two interest, 1 check the error messages and any log information.

If I need to make some changes what would be the easiest and straightforward way to capture logs and view them in Azure portal.  As you can see in the picture below unter Monitoring there are many ways are given to see the logs but I am not sure where to go.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- The app service will create an application insights of the same name.
- This application Insights will contain all the   logs regarding the web app along with performance data and other telemetry data too.
- You can view logs live under `live metrics` tab in application insights of the same name as web app .
- Here I have deployed a  simple mvc app which logs using Ilogger (typical boilerplate app which visual studio provides ) . IT will log once I refresh the page.
  [image]

Refer these [MS DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net) on application insights